# DE whose solutions are orthogonal to some vector field

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to find a differential equation whose solution yields a family of curves in the plane that move orthogonally to the vector field $\langle x-y,y^2\rangle$.

Any vector's slope that is orthogonal to the vector field $\langle x-y,y^2\rangle$ is given by $\dfrac{-y^2}{x-y}$, right? So I'm looking for a curve $y$ such that $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{-y^2}{x-y}$. But the solution says that it must be $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{x-y}{-y^2}$. What am I thinking wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If the vector has slope $S$, then it is in direction $(1,S)$.
It is orthogonal to $(x-y,y^2)$, so $(1,S).(x-y,y^2)=0=x-y+Sy^2$